# Set default value programmatically in ListPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I'm trying to set the default value of a `ListPreference` programmatically, but it has no effect. I am inflating the preference from xml, and then setting the values dynamically.

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
ListPreference sizePreference = findPreference("picture_size");
sizePreference.setEntries(entries);
sizePreference.setEntryValues(entryValues);
sizePreference.setDefaultValue(entryValues[0]);

bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(sizePreference);
```

Is there a way to do this without having to override `Preference`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setValueIndex(int index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setValueIndex(int index)?

```
sizePreference.setValueIndex(0);
```